# Struct consumes too much memory

Tags: c++, struct

I'm doing a school assignment dealing with Structs in C++. The assignment does not allow the use of STL or `new`/`delete`.

I'm representing items in a magazine.

```
struct PLACE {
    int itemCount;
    int etiquette[2];
};

struct SHELF {
    int placesCount;
    PLACE places[128];
};

struct RACK {
    int shelvesCount;
    SHELF shelves[128]; 
};

struct MAG {
    int racksCount;
    RACK racks[5];
};
```

Now, when I run the following code, it works fine, but if I change the length of racks array to something like 20, I get a runtime error (code.exe has stopped working).

```
PLACE place1 = {1, {1,2}};
SHELF shelf1 = {2, {place1}};   
RACK rack1 = {3, {shelf1}};
MAG mag1 = {1, {rack1}};
```

It seems that I'm exceeding some sort of memory? I would have thought that unlikely since when I calculated it, (when racks length is 5) I'm only using (((12 * 128) + 4) * 128 + 4) * 5 + 4 bytes, which is around 1MB.

`EDIT:`

I asked my instructor for some clarification on this. He told me that it's possible than my *heap* is exceeded, not *stack*, because: (quote)

> Stack deals with function calls and stack exceeded could be caused by
>   for example recursion, while here we're dealing with large data, so
>   it's rather the heap being exceeded.

He also told me that it's possible that my computer just has a lower limit (around 4MB), while the server that our code is being checked on has been allocated 1GB to handle this much data.

Don't know if this is true though, because from what I read online, both stack and heap can be allocated variables and stack isn't reserved purely for function calls, but also for variables inside of these functions...

Comment: If you are on linux then `ulimit -s` will show you the maximum stack size you are allowed to use (in kb). On my machine this is 8Mb and so 1Mb limit seems weird. But YMMV.

Comment: "_which is around 1MB._" Stack size, is, also, around several megabytes in size.

Comment: On a 64 bit platform that's going to be "around" 2MB. Now, what else is declared in auto storage that must've pushed the grand total into several hundred megabyte range? Failure to provide an [mcve] makes it impossible to have a complete analysis.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's not true. For the vast majority of C compilers, the type `int` has 32 bits even on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: It takes 1MB when length is 5, and then it works. But when I increase it further it stops working. So yeah, I must be exceeding the stack, which I have just learned exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a lot of *automatic storage duration* here. It's unlikely your compiler and architecture will permit any more than about 1Mb of such stuff.

Fortunately, the solution is trivial.

Use `std::vector` in place of the arrays: e.g.

```
struct MAG {
    // int racksCount; no need for this if you use a std::vector
    std::vector<RACK> racks;
};
```

and so on. `std::vector` puts most of its payload in *dynamic memory* which is why this approach will work. There are other C++ standard library containers too, but a good rule of thumb is to use a `std::vector` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Shame it's a school assignment and the OP is likely going to counter with the usual "can't use the standard library" that so many instructors impose for some daft reason. Oh well, +1.

Comment: AFAIK neither compiler nor architecture governs the stack size limit. It's OS dependent (and also customizable).

Comment: As @StoryTeller guessed, I can't use anything other than arrays and array pointers. And the maximum number of racks is indeed 128 in the assignment. Furthermore, the maximum number of MAGs in the total inventory is also 128. And the testing computer's memory limit is specified as 1GB - though I don't know what that means in this case. Because clearly it's not stack size.

Comment: Can you use new/delete at least?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: Yeah but then you have to worry about copying, assignment, and destruction. I don't know about you but I'm too old for that.

Comment: I think @MatthieuBrucher is (or should be) suggesting the workaround for "don't use `std`" of writing a `std::vector` approximation, and using that instead.

Comment: @Caleth: Then why not go the whole hog and implement the thing in BCPL? Who needs types beyond a machine word anyway?

Comment: Because it's a *workaround*, for the ridiculous requirement. If that requirement can be removed, you can drop the workaround

Comment: @Bathsheba yes, it was a `std::vector` that I suggested (and I hate `using namespace std`). The remark for new/delete was for OP, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you run out of stack.

This is especially the case because you are copying data from `place1` in `shelf1` and the same for all oothers, all that just for one element. Use a `std::vector` instead of static arrays.

If you can't because it's an assignment, you can still use `new`/`delete` to use heap instead of stack.

If not, cross your fingers, and try to use:

```
MAG mag1 = {1, {{3, {{2, {{1, {1,2}}}}}}}};
```

Ugly, and you don't know what objects you are populating, but should work on modern compilers.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately can't use dynamic memory allocation either. I think I might be well over the 1MB if I'm actually copying all of them over and over again. I thought this might happen.

Comment: unfortunately same problem occurs. I think it's simply because it so quickly spirals into massive size. I have 12 bytes in PLACE, So when I initialize a MAG, it needs space for 12 *  128 * 128 * number of racks.         I tried using pointers instead, but no luck either.